# ion-virtual-scroll does not grow when using a mat-expansion-panel

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

So I want to combine `virtual scroll` of `Ionic` with a `mat-expansion-panel` of `Angular`. But because the item is a fixed size, it does not expand anymore. Also, when scrolling the items layout gets messed up by not every item having same distance from each other. How can I fix this?

HTML:

```
<mat-accordion>
    <ion-virtual-scroll [items]="listItems">
        <div *virtualItem='let item'>
            <mat-expansion-panel>
                <mat-expansion-panel-header>
                    <mat-panel-title>
                        Test
                    </mat-panel-title>
                    <mat-panel-description>
                        Description
                    </mat-panel-description>
                </mat-expansion-panel-header>
                Test 123
            </mat-expansion-panel>
        </div>
    </ion-virtual-scroll>
</mat-accordion>
```

TS:

```
export class AppComponent {
  listItems = Array.from({length: 100000}).map((_, i) => `Item #${i}`);
}
```

Stackblitz example:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-v4-angular-tabs-kizer8

Comment: Did you have any luck here? I am having exactly the same issue with an expander.

Comment: Not exactly. Instead, I decided to use this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/details It is thousands of times faster and since you use virtual scroll for performance it is ideal. You just need to style it yourself that’s the only drawback but it is no big deal. I highly recommend.

Comment: Ok, thanks for that I will check it out. I have found a few others I was going to investigate, eg the Angular ngVFor etc [ie this](https://web.dev/virtualize-lists-with-angular-cdk), and [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngvforlib)

Comment: I used it in combination with the infinite scroll of ionic which worked great for me without any lag issues

Comment: Ok, never thought of the infinite scroll. Currently trying the Angular CDK cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport which seems to allow my expander to expand - looks promising, but need to test some more (and I need to set the height to something small, but seemed to work in my initial tests so far)